# Verification for a series of limits

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, alternative-proof, limits-without-lhopital

I ask kindly if my steps for these limits are right.

I start, always immediatly, checking the domain and this is an advice for my students of an high school.

I have, for example this function where the domain of

$$\operatorname{dom}\left(\frac{(1-x)^{\sqrt x}}{x-2}\right)=\{x\in \Bbb R \colon 0\leq x \leq 1\}$$

and I think that it is not possible to write that $x\to +\infty$

If I have the function $g(x)=\left(\frac{x-1}{x-2}\right)^{\sqrt x}$ where it is possibile to have $x\to +\infty$, my steps are:

$$\lim _{x\to +\infty }\left(\frac{x-1}{x-2}\right)^{\sqrt x}=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x-2}\right)^{\sqrt x}= \lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x-2}\right)^{\frac{(x-2)\sqrt x}{x-2}} $$

$$=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{x-2}\right)^{x-2}\right]^{\sqrt{\frac{x}{(x-2)^2}}}=e^0=1  $$

If the function is:

$$\psi(x)=\frac{(x-1)^{\sqrt x}}{x-2}$$

it is possible from the simple domain that  $x\to +\infty$,
$$\lim _{x\to +\infty }\frac{(x-1)^{\sqrt x}}{x-2}=\lim _{x\to +\infty }\frac{e^{\sqrt{x}\ln \left(x-1\right)}}{x-2}=\frac{e^{\lim _{x\to +\infty}x\sqrt{x}\,\frac{\ln (x-1)}{x}}}{x-2} \tag{A}$$

Being $$\lim _{x\to +\infty \:}\frac{\ln \left(x-1\right)}{x}=0 \tag{B}$$

I will have the exponent $x\sqrt{x}\,\frac{\ln (x-1)}{x}$ (in (A) last step) an indeterminate form $(\infty\cdot0)$. Is there a strategy without the use of the L'Hopital rule for the (A)?

Comment: Limit of the second function $\psi$ doesn't exist.

Comment: @Koro I'm happy to know the limit of $\psi$ doesn't exist, because I have done many calculus on my papers. Is there a reason, please?

Comment: Sebastiano, I am unable to understand the last sentence talking about the exponents of something. Did you mean checking the exponent of x ?, I read on an old post that you use a translator, can you write in your native language (here in the comments)

Comment: Please have a look at my answer below.

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi Excuse me very much but often I use Deepl translator. Now is it clear? (Now I'm not using the translator :-))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's not use L'Hopital's rule in $(A)$.

$$\bbox[yellow,5px,border:2px solid red]{\frac{(x-1)^{\sqrt x}}{x-2}=\frac{x^{(\sqrt x-1)}(1-x^{-1})^{x(\sqrt x)^{-1}}}{1-2x^{-1}}=P(x)\cdot Q(x)}\tag{1}$$

where, $$P(x)=x^{(\sqrt x-1)}, \quad \text{and} \quad  Q(x)=\frac{(1-x^{-1})^{x(\sqrt x)^{-1}}}{1-2x^{-1}}$$

Note that $\lim_{x\to \infty} Q(x)=1$  ($\,\text{Numerator}$ of $Q(x)$ tends to $e^0=1$).

Assume on the contrary that limit in $(1)$ exists(finitely) as $x\to \infty$ and is equal to $L\in \mathbb R$.

Hence by limit rules, $P(x)=\dfrac{P(x)Q(x)}{Q(x)}\implies \lim_{x\to \infty} P(x)=L$, which is a contradiction (do you see why?).

Hence, the limit doesn't exist finitely.

Comment: Meantime thank you very much. I'm editing your answer with a look more fine :-)

Comment: You are welcome @Sebastiano.

Comment: What is $N^r$ comparated with $Q(x)=\frac{(1-x^{-1})^{x(\sqrt x)^{-1}}}{1-2x^{-1}}$?

Comment: @Sebastiano: I meant Numerator of $Q(x)$ i.e. $(1-x^{-1})^{x(\sqrt x)^{-1}}$.